# How to Retrieve data from Multiple Tables in MySQL single Query?

Tags: mysql

I have a Database where the tables are as follows:

Table Name: `userDB`
Column Name: `user_id` (CUSTOMER'S ID), `reseller_id` (RESELLER WHO HAS SOLD CONNECTION TO CUSTOMER)

Table Name: `serverDB`
Column Name: `server_id` (SERVER'S ID) , `status` (UP OR DOWN STATUS - if 1 DOWN, if 0 UP)

Table Name: `usageDB_january`
Column Name: `user_id` (CUSTOMER'S ID) , `server_id` (SERVER'S ID)
...
Table Name: `usageDB_december`
Column Name: `user_id` (CUSTOMER'S ID) , `server_id` (SERVER'S ID)

NOTE: There are 12 tables from `usageDB_january` to `usageDB_december` for each month.

In a PHP page I have listed the `server_id` which are DOWN (Status 1)

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__
| SERIAL NO | ID of DOWN SERVERS |
| 1                 |                            28839              |
| 2                         |                            20283              |
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

While I will click on ID of DOWN SERVERS I want to show the list of RESELLERS under that SERVER ID.

I am not understanding that how to write the MySQL Query.

Can you kindly help me? Please?

I have no way to change the Database Table Structure. I am not understanding the query.

SELECT `reseller_id`  
FROM `userDB`  
WHERE `user_id` = ( 
                SELECT `user_id`  
                FROM `usageDB_january` 
                WHERE `server_id` LIKE '17090' 
                UNION 
                SELECT `user_id`  
                FROM `usageDB_february` 
                WHERE `server_id` LIKE '17090' 
            );

Error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: I am understanding that Join will be better, but I am not understanding the format of writing the SQL query. I tried but failed. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Learn about SQL and `JOIN`s.  MySQL documentation is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html.  W3Schools at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp.  Tell people what you tried, please.

Comment: You should show what you tried. We have no idea what kind of relation exists between tables.

Comment: Please at least spend a minute or two edit your question and post `DESC ` for all three tables, relevant sample data, and desired output.

Comment: @Nirjhor - if there is any option to change database table, instead of usageDB table for each month use a single table. Then you can write your required query very easily. Query to create that one table is    CREATE TABLE `usageDB` (
 `user_id` INT(10) NULL,
 `server_id` INT(10) NULL,
 `monthNo` INT(10) NULL
)

Comment: Unfortunately huge data is being handled, and as already the system is developed with 12 table, I am not able (and not authorized) to change the data table structure... I was trying some solution and found an error. I know I'm wrong someway... But I don't know what might be the exact solution.  Thanks everyone for valuable comments. If anyone can give me a solution it would be really great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your queries:

```
SELECT user_id, server_id, reseller_id
FROM usageDB_january
JOIN userDB ON usageDB_january.user_id=userDB.user_id
UNION
SELECT user_id, server_id, reseller_id
FROM usageDB_february
JOIN userDB ON usageDB_february.user_id=userDB.user_id
UNION
// ... continue with all the other months
```